# Bootstrap responsive input form fields

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using .input-lg to make the form fields large. My expectation is that when the viewport shrinks (less than 768px by bootstrap default), that the form fields would become smaller and take on the normal  settings, but they are not. Any ideas? Does bootstrap handle this scenario?

**UPDATE:**

HTML

```
   <form class="form-inline" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="sr-only" for="searchZipcode">Zipcode</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg input-search" id="searchZipcode" placeholder="Zipcode of home?">
      </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: post more code, and yes bootstrap handles that scenario with the bootstrap grid system. read about it here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: @bto.rdz code posted. I dont see that bootstrap has that handled automatically. At this point it seems I would gave to build my own media queries. Is that the only solution?

Comment: It won't. `input-lg` affects the height of the elements. `col-lg-x` affects the width. [In the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes)

Comment: yes jsut as @Ross said

Comment: @Ross Bummer. Is the only way to write my own media query? Also, anyone have a resource to the default input settings (height, padding, font-size, line-space, etc...?

Comment: If you omit the `input-lg` class, you get bootraps defaults. The actual vendor default values vary across browsers, hence why you are using a CSS reset/framework. Here's about 10px difference in `inpug-lg` and `input-default`, it probably isn't worth spending much time on.

Answer (score 8):

I think you must put your input within a div. the input-xx class is not, lets say, responsive :D

```
 <div class="col-xx-xx"> // change xx-xx to some accepted value like sm-4, md-10, whatever it fits you.
     <input class="input-lg">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Bootstrap cannot handle this scenario. Thanks everyone for the comments and answers.

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer to use a contenteditable div for that reason. You can apply the bootstrap classes to make the width responsive.  You can give it a border if you want to, to make it look like an input. Use textContent instead of value to access the data, and use the focusout event instead of the change event.

Answer (score -2):

I've encountered this problem, too. I've fixed it by adding

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

in the head section of the html. Be careful, though, because this would also disable zooming.

Comment: What you are doing has nothing to do with the question. You are setting your viewport. If you are expecting your site to be responsive and adapting to "small" devices, it should be already set that way somehow. Furthermore, if you want to get exactly the same results without disabling zooming, you only need to remove the `maximum-scale=1` part.