# input width in form-inline bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't understand, how I can customize an input (form-control) width in Bootstrap 3?

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <form role="form" class="form-inline">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Почтовый идентификатор" id="search"> 
                  </div>
                    <input type="button" class="btn  btn-success" value="Найти" onclick="window.location.href = '/result/'+document.getElementById('search').value">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Can I do it without some styles (like width in pixels)?

Answer (score 4):

**Update** (W3Schools link added):
I just spotted that there's a very good answer on this issue available at: [w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_sizing.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_sizing.asp). There are good examples on how to apply either `.input-lg` and `.input-sm` for input height or `.col-lg-*` and `.col-sm-` for input width.

**Original answer**:
Have you tried to use Bootstrap [Grids](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed) with your Form and col-xs-.. classes for each input field that needs to be stacked on mobile device. Something like the code below (copy pasted from Bootstrap):

```
<!-- Stack the columns on mobile by making one full-width and the other half-width -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

I applied those col-xs-.. classes on to your form, and got your columns stacked on a mobile device (okay I just made my browser window smaller and it worked).

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <form role="form" class="form-inline">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2"> 
                    <div class="form-group">  
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Почтовый идентификатор" id="search">  
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-1">
                        <input type="button" class="btn  btn-success" value="Найти" onclick="window.location.href = '/result/' + document.getElementById('search').value"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

On Desktop device I gave those fields smaller values: col-md-2 and col-md-1, but you may want to fine-tune those values the way you like it.

**Updated:**
Have you thought about making your custom colors and sizes by using LESS variables for your input elements, which Bootstrap allows you to do: *"Customize Less variables to define colors, sizes and more inside your custom CSS stylesheets."*

If you check the [Customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#forms) part of Bootstrap site. It allows you to customize input elements in your Form. LESS variables such as: *@input-bg, @input-color, @input-height-base, @input-border* and others could be useful in your case. For instance *@input-height-base* is by default *.form-control* height.

Comment: @КонстантинРусанов I realized today that I didn't reply to your question yesterday; instead I provided you with some settings that help you with your layout when viewing your page in different devices that also have an effect on the size of the fields. Today, I realized that you might wanna customize your settings

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
.form-inline .form-group input {
    width:140px;
}
```

For the css to manipu

Answer (score -1):

You can quickly size labels and form controls within a Horizontal form by adding `.form-group-*` to the  element

You can also quickly size all inputs and other elements inside an `.input-group`with the `.input-group-sm` or `.input-group-lg` classes

Comment: i need mobile responsive, not hard size in px

Comment: @КонстантинРусанов: input classes provided by bootstrap are not responsive. You need to wrap them in div like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21036484/1719752

Comment: @Milind Anantwar, I think in Bootstrap v.3.1.1 (bootstrap.css file) only input-lg and input-sm are available. So I guess you referring to an older version of Bootstrap(?), maybe. I'm quite new to Bootstrap and currently learning how to use v.3.1.1 :-)

Comment: In Bootstrap v3, `input-lg` and `input-sm` affect height, **not width**.

Comment: @jyrkim: would be great if you can update the newer syntax if you are familiar with it :)

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Good comment :-) I just spotted that there's a pretty good answer on this issue already available at: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_sizing.asp After having a look I discovered that there are good examples on how to apply either .input-lg and .input-sm for input height or .col-lg-* and .col-sm- for input width. I'm going to add that link on to my answer. Cheers :-)